# mysql select function running twice

Tags: mysql

I want to use a function inside a select query.
This is my test database.

When I use a select, get a result, but the function is running twice... why? I want to insert one row in this case.

Help, please!

```
create database db1_test;
use db1_test;

create table t1(
id int(11) primary key auto_increment,
t1col1 varchar(20) not null,
t1col2 int(1) not null
);

create table t2(
id int(11) primary key auto_increment,
t2col1 int(11) not null,
t2col2 datetime
);

insert into t1 (t1col1, t1col2) values ('row1', 1);
insert into t1 (t1col1, t1col2) values ('row2', 0);
insert into t1 (t1col1, t1col2) values ('row4', 1);

drop function if exists func1;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION func1(id int) RETURNS datetime
BEGIN
insert into t2 (`t2col1`, `t2col2`) values (id, now());
RETURN now();
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

TEST :

```
SELECT id, t1col2, func1(id) FROM `t1` WHERE 1 and `t1`.`t1col1`='row1';
SELECT id, t1col2, func1(id) FROM `t1` WHERE 1 and `t1`.`t1col1`='row2';
SELECT id, t1col2, func1(id) FROM `t1` WHERE 1 and `t1`.`t1col1`='row4';
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wpUkDDWZFs4pqiD1QYLw4/0

Comment: Seems a pointless function why not just INSERT..SELECT?

Comment: Interesting... In my localhost phpmyadmin, when I'm running a test select, it inserts twice to t2 table.
In your fiddle... running just once.

Sorry I don't understand your second answer. please write a real insert..select question, thanks

Comment: maybe I'm understand it.... I want to send just one question from arduino to mysql, one select for a result, but I want directly inserting the result another table.

Answer (score 1):

Functions are generally used to store reuseable code which returns a scalar value from a calculation or transformation. I think you could

```
insert into t2(t2col1,t2col2)
SELECT id, now()
FROM `t1` 
WHERE `t1`.`t1col1`='row1';
```

Comment: thanks, it's a good idea... I use it before, but I want to know the select result!

so in this case I must send another question for the result...

another tips?